# Where to add multiindex level in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I have a multiindex dataframe, I provided minimal reproducable sample.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    ([2020], [1, 2, 3, 4]), names=['year', 'q']
)

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    (['Items1', 'Items2', 'Items3'], ['new', 'old']),
    names=['Items', 'type']
)

data = np.random.seed(123)
data = list(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), (4,6)))

Ldata = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
Ldata
```

And I want to mark certain values in dataframe, and I'm doing it like this. But I don't know where to put multiindex `level=1`. I tried but I got errors, where I can add level?

```
def highlight_cells(x):
    c = 'background-color: white'
    c1 = 'background-color: red'
    c2 = 'background-color: blue'
    c3 = 'background-color: green'
                
    k1 = Ldata['new'].str.contains("a", na=False) 
    k2 = Ldata['new'].str.contains("b", na=False)
    k3 = Ldata['new'].str.contains("c", na=False) 
    
    colordata = pd.DataFrame(c, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    colordata.loc[k1, 'new'] = c1
    colordata.loc[k2, 'new'] = c2
    colordata.loc[k3, 'new'] = c3

    return colordata

end = Ldata.style.apply(highlight_cells,axis=None)

end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward modification would be to use the `subset` argument of [`Styler.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) in conjunction with [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html). Then reduce from DataFrame applied styles to Series level applied styles for each column in the MultiIndex matching the subset:

```
def highlight_cells(x):
    c = 'background-color: white'
    c1 = 'background-color: red'
    c2 = 'background-color: blue'
    c3 = 'background-color: green'

    k1 = x.str.contains("a", na=False)
    k2 = x.str.contains("b", na=False)
    k3 = x.str.contains("c", na=False)
    
    # Build Series for _column_ level Styles
    color_data = pd.Series(c, index=x.index)
    color_data[k1] = c1
    color_data[k2] = c2
    color_data[k3] = c3
    return color_data


idx = pd.IndexSlice
end = Ldata.style.apply(highlight_cells, subset=idx[:, idx[:, 'new']])

end
```

---

Naturally this can be done without the separate variables as well:

```
def highlight_cells(x):
    color_data = pd.Series('background-color: white', index=x.index)
    color_data[x.str.contains("a", na=False)] = 'background-color: red'
    color_data[x.str.contains("b", na=False)] = 'background-color: blue'
    color_data[x.str.contains("c", na=False)] = 'background-color: green'
    return color_data


idx = pd.IndexSlice
end = Ldata.style.apply(highlight_cells, subset=idx[:, idx[:, 'new']])

end
```

---

Or without building an indexed structure with [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
def highlight_cells(x):
    return np.select(
        [x.str.contains("a", na=False),
         x.str.contains("b", na=False),
         x.str.contains("c", na=False)],
        ['background-color: red',
         'background-color: blue',
         'background-color: green'],
        default='background-color: white'
    )


idx = pd.IndexSlice
end = Ldata.style.apply(highlight_cells, subset=idx[:, idx[:, 'new']])

end
```

---

All options produce:

[image: styled table]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the easiest way is to stack the DataFrame like this before applying the function:

```py
Ldata = Ldata.stack('Items')
```

Then you can leave the rest of your code as it is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to modify every `"new"` column, across levels of `"Items"` columns.

You can use [`IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html) to access inner levels of a MultiIndex:

```py
def highlight_cells(x):
    c = 'background-color: white'
    c1 = 'background-color: red'
    c2 = 'background-color: blue'
    c3 = 'background-color: green'

    def ldata_contains(value):
        return (
            Ldata
            .loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'new']]
            .apply(lambda y: y.str.contains(value, na=False))
        )

    k1 = ldata_contains("a")
    k2 = ldata_contains("b")
    k3 = ldata_contains("c")

    colordata = pd.DataFrame(c, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    colordata.loc[k1, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'new']] = c1
    colordata.loc[k2, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'new']] = c2
    colordata.loc[k3, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'new']] = c3

    return colordata
```

Comment: This won't work because `Ldata.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'new']]` will return a DataFrame. and There is not a `DataFrame.str.contains` method.

Comment: True. You'd have to `.apply` it then.

Comment: I modified it to use `.apply`, with a small helper function. You don't need the helper function, of course, you can just copy and paste.

Comment: Now `k1`, `k2`, and `k3` are DataFrames but you're passing them to the index slice of `loc`.